# How do print the data between two dates set by user in my CSV file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a CSV file where it stores a book, its author and the year it was published (this file is made from user input). Now I want to ask the user for a starting year and an ending year, and the program should display all the books from the data set published during that time frame. I'm just not sure how to do this

Here is my code so far:

```
import csv

amount = int(input("How many records would you like to add: "))
count = 0

with open("Books.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(["", "Book", "Author", "Year released"])

while count < amount:

     book = input("Enter a book: ")
     author = input("Enter it's Author: ")
     year = input("Enter the year it released: ")

    headers = [count, book, author, year]
    with open("Books.csv", "a", newline="") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(headers)

    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you can read a csv using [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Books.csv")
```

Now you can filter records from based on year column

```
filter = (df['Year released'] > start_date) & (df['Year released'] <= end_date)
filter_df = df.loc[filter]
```

To select the books :

```
books = filter_df['Book'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is a very good option as Rajat Mishra said - you could also do it with the built-in CSV module:

```
books = []

with open("books.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for row in reader:
        count, book, author, release_year = row
        print(row)
        if release_year is int:
            if int(release_year) > start_year and int(release_year) < end_year:
                books.append(book)


print(books)
```

Comment: I am getting this error:     if int(release_year) > start_year and int(release_year) < end_year:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Year released'

Comment: @wdEW34 I've added a change for this.

Comment: I have a few questions, (1) I'm asking the user for the start year and end year so should I add that and (2) I tried your code with the changes but the output is [ ] with no data inside it

Comment: @wdEW34 

(1) You could do start year as `start_year = int(input("What start year?"))`, end year as `end_year = int(input("What end year?"))`

(2) I would do some debugging including `print(row)` to check where you that the error may be coming from.

Comment: I did the first part but how do I debug my code? I don't really see where the problem is in my code. Perhaps you can see what's wrong from my code above?

Comment: Without seeing your CSV file etc. I won't be able to. The best idea is to place `print` statements throughout the code and see if you get the expected output

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are able to sort the column by using the built-in sorted function.

```
import operator
with open("Books.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(3), reverse=False)
```

We send 3 parameters to the sorted function:

- **reader** parameter is the reader object that belongs to the .csv we want to read.
- **key** parameter indicates the column that will the csv file be sorted based on.
- **reverse** parameter tells the way sorting, like False = Ascending, True = Descending.